# List of all functions in base R?

Tags: r

CRAN provides [manuals for each CRAN package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html) and the manuals contain a list of every function (and dataset) contained in those CRAN packages.

Is there something similar for base R? i.e. where can be found a list of all the functions in base R?

Comment: Like [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html)?

Comment: @jay.sf I will read - lots of info,  I notice section 5.1.1 lists all packages that come with R, which is handy. Does any section of the doc list all the functions in base R?

Comment: @jay.sf from a quick scan I don't think the doc contains a list of all base R functions (it looks like excellent reading though, so thanks)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the [reference card](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf), I don't know if it's complete though.

Comment: `help(package = 'base')` and/or `library(help = 'base')`, and similar for the other packages that are part of "base R"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by user *alistaire* in a comment, `help(package = 'base')` will show an index of the functions in the `base` package.

However, “base R” is generally understood to encompass more than just the `base` package, namely the other packages that are also by default loaded by R. This list of packages is accessible via `getOption('defaultPackages')` (but note that this list is user modifiable, e.g. in `~/.Rprofile`!).

As of R 3.6.1, this list is (and has been, for a while)

```
[1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"
```

If you want to list all exported symbols from these packages, you could use, for instance

```
base_packages = getOption('defaultPackages')
names(base_packages) = base_packages
lapply(base_packages, function (pkg) ls(paste0('package:', pkg)))
```

Comment: Great answer. `sapply(getOption('defaultPackages'), function (pkg) ls(paste0('package:', pkg)))` is briefer.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Yes but I strongly advise `sapply` altogether (except perhaps, very carefully, in interactive usage) because its return type is nondeterministic: it can be a flat vector, an array/matrix or a list, and this is generally not known before calling the function. This property is extremely error-prone. My answers and other teaching material therefore never use it.

Answer (score 3):

As of R 4.2.1 version, the codes below will give you full lists of R base functions.

```r
library(help = "base")
```

Answer (score 1):

CRAN actually provides full documentation for the standard base library too, i.e. in addition to user-contributed CRAN packages: https://search.r-project.org/R/doc/html/packages.html

Here is the base package's help documentation, for example: https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/00Index.html

As a general observation, CRAN's refmans pages are simultaneously underrated and more obscure than they should be. We can probably blame the opportunistic SEO of various data science companies for this annoying outcome. Plus the refmans versions are always up to date, unlike some other options. (Looking at you, DataCamp/RDocumentation.)

Comment: Say I click on your first link, and then click on 'base' (the first item in the list), then it comes up with another very long list - is that very long list all the functions in the 'base' package? (if so, this is very good to know - just want to confirm that that's what it actually is - I spot-tested a couple of the items and it appears that's what it is)

Comment: Hi @stevec, that's right. (You won't see unexported or low-level (e.g. C-level) functions. But you probably aren't looking for those anyway.)

Comment: That's great. In that case this answer is as good as [@konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58608856/5783745)'s (I wish both could be accepted answers because they are both great).

Comment: Thanks and nps... I was rather late to the party, after all ;-)